# Non-invariant subspaces for subfactors.

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, subfactors

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a II_1 factor. If $\mathcal{N}$ is a subfactor of $\mathcal{M}$ ($\mathcal{N} \neq \mathcal{M}$), does there always exist a projection in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $(I-P)AP \neq 0$ for any $A$ in $\mathcal{N}$ such that $A \neq zI$?

Comment: Why can't I take $A=I$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the restriction that A can not be a scalar.

Comment: You probably want to exclude the case $\mathcal N = \mathcal M$ as well.

Comment: Yemon and Jesse, thank you for pointing out my mistakes. Do you guys know any relative results about this question?

Comment: Echoing Polya: what is the **simplest** case that you cannot do? Presumably you know examples of factors and subfactors.